# Java webdrivermanager is not opening browsers in jenkins ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have the last webdrivermanager version, and when I run `mvn clean test` in the terminal the project compiles and runs perfectly.

The problem is when I run the same on a local jenkins machine, the browsers do not open.

I have these options enabled

```
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("enable-automation");
            options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("--disable-translate", "--disable-gpu", "--verbose", "--privileged");
            options.addArguments("--disable-info");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
            options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
            options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
```

Any ideas why in console is working but running on a local jenkins is not opening the browsers ?

I got this msg error `jenkins org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`

Launching the job from jenkins terminal with `mvn clean test`

Note I also tried Xvfb but didn't show up also.

Comment: Are you running multiple test classes via xml file ?

Comment: yes I have this xml

<suite name="Regression" parallel="classes" thread-count="15"
       configfailurepolicy="continue" preserve-order="true">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utilities.reports.Listeners.TestListener"/>
        <listener class-name="utilities.reports.Listeners.AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>

 <test name="Smoke">
        <classes>
             class 1
             class 2
             ...

Comment: Are using maven and how did you linked your .xml file via pom.xml?
did you use surefire plugins?

Comment: is linked in pom file, and yes I use surefire, works on terminal

Comment: is your build getting failed on Jenkins?

Comment: Is getting failed for how chromedriver works,

Comment: can you check console output and what is error message and please update question with that error message